VNCSharp VNC Viewer Black Screen
I have a VNC Viewer that tiles multiple connections to Linux VNC servers so I can see all screens in one Windows Forms app (.net 8.0).
I have coded the detection of black screens to try and reconnect but it seems that it's not working.
Here is what happens after some time, see picture below.
How can I make sure that the connection always stays live like when I use RealVNC Viewer?
Here is the code
    // Handle connection lost
 EventHandler connectionLostHandler = null;
 connectionLostHandler = async (sender, e) =>
 {
     rd.ConnectionLost -= connectionLostHandler; // Unsubscribe immediately

     if (_attempt < _maxAttempts)
     {
         _attempt++; // Increment attempt count
         await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, _attempt))); // Exponential backoff
         if (rd.IsConnected) // Check if still connected
         {
             rd.Disconnect(); // Disconnect before reconnecting
         }
         rd.Connect(_arg1, true, true); // Try to reconnect
     }
     else
     {
         EventLogger.WriteToLog($"Failed to reconnect to {_arg1} after {_maxAttempts} attempts.", EventLogEntryType.Error);
     }
 };
 rd.ConnectionLost += connectionLostHandler;

  private async Task CheckAndRecoverBlackScreenAsync(RemoteDesktop rd, string arg1)
  {
      if (IsScreenBlack(rd))
      {
          EventLogger.WriteToLog("Black screen detected. Attempting to recover " + arg1 + ".", EventLogEntryType.Warning);

          if (_attempt < _maxAttempts)
          {
              _attempt++; // Increment attempt count
              await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, _attempt))); // Exponential backoff

              if (rd.IsConnected) // Check if still connected
              {
                  rd.Disconnect(); // Disconnect before reconnecting
              }
              rd.Connect(arg1, true, true); // Try to reconnect
          }
          else
          {
              EventLogger.WriteToLog($"Failed to recover from black screen after {_maxAttempts} attempts for " + arg1 + ".", EventLogEntryType.Error);
          }
      }
      else
      {
          _attempt = 0; // Reset attempt count if the screen is not black
      }
  }

  private bool IsScreenBlack(RemoteDesktop rd)
  {
      // Check if the control is visible and has a valid size
      if (rd.Width <= 0 || rd.Height <= 0 || !rd.Visible)
      {
          return false;
      }

      Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rd.Width, rd.Height);
      rd.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, rd.Width, rd.Height));

      for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
      {
          for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
          {
              Color pixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
              if (pixelColor.R != 0 || pixelColor.G != 0 || pixelColor.B != 0)
              {
                  return false; // Found a non-black pixel
              }
          }
      }
      return true; // All pixels are black
  }


